# How to access implement member property in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Hey I am working in kotlin. I create a tree data structure. I create open class called **VariantNode** and implement in three child class **QuantityNode**, **StrengthNode**, **SubscriptionNode**.

**VariantNode.kt**

```
open class VariantNode {
    var value: ProductValue? = null
    var children: MutableList<VariantNode> = arrayListOf()
}
```

**QuantityNode.kt**

```
class QuantityNode : VariantNode() {
    var defaultValue: Boolean? = null
}
```

**StrengthNode.kt**

```
class StrengthNode : VariantNode() {
    var pricePerUnit: String? = null
    var defaultValue: Boolean? = null
}
```

**SubscriptionNode.kt**

```
class SubscriptionNode : VariantNode() {
    var defaultValue: Boolean? = null
}
```

I want to access **defaultValue** and set value, but I am getting error `Unresolved reference: defaultValue`

**ActivityViewModel.kt**

```
class ActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var baseNode: VariantNode = VariantNode()
    private val defaultValueId = "12643423243324"

    init {
        createGraph()
    }

    private fun createGraph() {
        val tempHashMap: MutableMap<String, VariantNode> = mutableMapOf()
        val getUnSortedDataList = getUnSortedDataList()
        val sortedList = getUnSortedDataList.sortedWith(
            compareBy<ProductVariant> {   // or compareByDescending
                it.strength?.value?.toInt() ?: 0   // or java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE
            }.thenBy {                    // or thenByDescending
                it.quantity?.value?.toInt() ?: 0   // or java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE
            }
        )

        sortedList.forEach { productVariant ->
            productVariant.strength?.let { strength ->
                baseNode.defaultValue = productVariant.id == defaultValueId // getting error in here

                if (tempHashMap.containsKey("strength_${strength.value}")) {
                    return@let
                }
                val tempNode = StrengthNode().apply {
                    value = strength
                    pricePerUnit = productVariant.pricePerUnit?.value
                }
                baseNode.children.add(tempNode)
                tempHashMap["strength_${strength.value}"] = tempNode
            }
            productVariant.quantity?.let { quantity ->
                if (tempHashMap.containsKey("strength_${productVariant.strength?.value}_quantity_${quantity.value}")) {
                    return@let
                }
                val tempNode = QuantityNode().apply {
                    value = quantity
                }
                val parent =
                    tempHashMap["strength_${productVariant.strength?.value}"] ?: baseNode
                parent.children.add(tempNode)

                tempHashMap["strength_${productVariant.strength?.value}_quantity_${quantity.value}"] =
                    tempNode
            }
            productVariant.subscription?.let { subscription ->
                val tempNode = SubscriptionNode().apply {
                    value = subscription
                }
                val parent =
                    tempHashMap["strength_${productVariant.strength?.value}_quantity_${productVariant.quantity?.value}"]
                        ?: baseNode
                parent.children.add(tempNode)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

My idea to update the **defaultValue** because I have **defaultValueId** and want to match with this **defaultValue** and set in each variant node type. Any suggestion how to do in better way would be great. My [ActivityViewModel](https://github.com/vivek-modi/OptionsView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/optionsview/ActivityViewModel.kt) link

**UPDATE** after @snachmsm suggestion, I used first approach

```
private fun createGraph() {
        val tempHashMap: MutableMap<String, VariantNode> = mutableMapOf()
        val getUnSortedDataList = getUnSortedDataList()
        val sortedList = getUnSortedDataList.sortedWith(
            compareBy<ProductVariant> {   // or compareByDescending
                it.strength?.value?.toInt() ?: 0   // or java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE
            }.thenBy {                    // or thenByDescending
                it.quantity?.value?.toInt() ?: 0   // or java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE
            }
        )

        sortedList.forEach { productVariant ->
            productVariant.strength?.let { strength ->
                baseNode.defaultValue = productVariant.id == defaultValueId
                if (tempHashMap.containsKey("strength_${strength.value}")) {
                    return@let
                }
                val tempNode = StrengthNode().apply {
                    value = strength
                    pricePerUnit = productVariant.pricePerUnit?.value
                }
                baseNode.children.add(tempNode)
                tempHashMap["strength_${strength.value}"] = tempNode
            }
            productVariant.quantity?.let { quantity ->
                baseNode.defaultValue = productVariant.id == defaultValueId
                if (tempHashMap.containsKey("strength_${productVariant.strength?.value}_quantity_${quantity.value}")) {
                    return@let
                }
                val tempNode = QuantityNode().apply {
                    value = quantity
                }
                val parent =
                    tempHashMap["strength_${productVariant.strength?.value}"] ?: baseNode
                parent.children.add(tempNode)

                tempHashMap["strength_${productVariant.strength?.value}_quantity_${quantity.value}"] =
                    tempNode
            }
            productVariant.subscription?.let { subscription ->
                baseNode.defaultValue = productVariant.id == defaultValueId
                val tempNode = SubscriptionNode().apply {
                    value = subscription
                }
                val parent =
                    tempHashMap["strength_${productVariant.strength?.value}_quantity_${productVariant.quantity?.value}"]
                        ?: baseNode
                parent.children.add(tempNode)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`baseNode` is an `VariantNode` instance (as `sortedList` holds this type of objects) , which doesn't have own `defaultValue`, thus you can't access it. as all your extending classes contains it - this variable should be placed in `VariantNode` instead of each extender separately (duplicated code in fact), thats the purpose of object extending

```
open class VariantNode {
    var value: ProductValue? = null
    var children: MutableList<VariantNode> = arrayListOf()
    var defaultValue: Boolean? = null
}
```

and remove `defaultValue` from all other extending classes

another way is to check instance type of `baseNode`, but in your case this isn't proper approach

```
if(baseNode is QuantityNode) {
     (baseNode as QuantityNode).defaultValue = ...
}
else if(baseNode is SubscriptionNode) ...
```

first approach will reduce your whole code-base with two lines (3 removed, 1 added), second one will add whole cascade of `if`s, which will be copied into other places in code, in which you will iterate through `List`. and when you add new extender of `VariantNode` - you will have to inspect whole code base, looking for such `if` cascade and adding yet another `else if`. with first approach new `VariantNode` extender will inherit `defaultValue` automatically

Comment: I tried your code. But value is always is null?

Comment: well, by default it is as you have `defaultValue = null` currently in all classes. but "Unresolved reference" hint should be gone after my suggestion and this line will set up `defaultValue` variable

Comment: if you are talking about `var value: ProductValue` - its also `null`-defined on start and I don't see any line in posted code which is attaching any nun-`null` object to it

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I used your first suggestion.

Comment: can you help me how to compare value with my `defaultValueId` and set according?

Comment: just post new question, describe well new problem, attach related code and someone will probably help you. maybe it will be me if I will know answer, maybe it will be someone else :)

Comment: sure @snachmsm I'll ask. thanks a million for your help.